# Determining the stationary points of the function $ f(x,y)=x^{4}+x^2y+y^2+3 $

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Calculating the partial derivatives in $x$ and $y$ you find that the unique possible stationary point is the point $P(0,0)$, but when you calculate the determinant of the Hessian matrix is $|H|=0$. Based on this you can't get any information of this point with the Heissan matrix.

One way to solve this problem is to consider $x^4+x^2y+y^2$ as a polynomial of II grade in $x$ with the $\Delta <0$.

So this function is a polynomial ever positive + 3. Based on this you can say that 3 is the minimum value of this function, and you find that the point $P(0,0)$ must be a minimum.

May you figure any other method to solve this problem?

Is there a generic method to solve this kind of problems with $|H|=0$? Especially when you are not so lucky that a part of the function is a polynomial of II grade with $\Delta<0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that $$f(x,y)=(x^2+y)^2-x^2y+3.$$ Thus, if $y\le 0$ it is

$$f(x,y)\ge 3=f(0,0).$$ So assume $y>0.$ If $x\ne 0$ then because of the GM-AM inequality we have

$$\dfrac{x^2+y}{2}\ge \sqrt{x^2y}\implies (x^2+y)^2\ge 4x^2y>x^2y.$$ That is $f(x,y)>3.$ If $x=0$ then $$f(0,y)=y^2+3>3.$$ So $(0,0)$ is a global minimum of $f.$

Comment: Elegant and very simple. I didn't know about the GM-AM inequality and it's very useful in this case.

Answer (score 0):

prove that for your $f(x,y)$ is hold
$$x^4+x^2y+y^2+3\geq 3$$ for all real $(x,y)$

Answer (score 0):

HINT.-Another (quite elementary) way is to assume that
$$x^4+yx^2+y^2+3=3+h\text{ with } h\gt 0$$ Then, solving the quadratic equation in $x^2$,
$$x^2=-y+\sqrt{-(3y^2+h)}\text{which is impossible in }\mathbb R.$$